# Visualizing correlation between the answers of a multiple-choice question

Tags: data-visualization, survey

I have created a multiple-choice poll that asks respondents to select their favourite movie genres. The poll is very basic, it lists various movie genres by name - drama, sci-fi, action, etc. - and respondents can pick one or multiple.

I'd like to create a visualization of which answers usually go together. E.g. it could turn out that people often choose sci-fi and thriller together. Which is the most effective way to visualize this and how must the input data be prepared?

I was thinking of something like a [correlation network](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/250-correlation-network-with-igraph/), or something similar to StackOverflow [showing how technologies are connected](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#technology-_-how-technologies-are-connected) in their Developer Survey, however I don't have a strong background in statistics so I don't know how to apply it.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are the questions you pose in your survey, and what kinds of answers are possible? For instance, do you propose a couple (how many?) of genres like "sci-fi" and "thriller", and people can then rate them on a scale of 1 to 5?

Comment: Is a $\chi^2$ independence test what you need?

Comment: @David i don't think so. Here's a link to something very close to what i want to achieve: https://www.kaggle.com/jncharon/python-network-graph. I need to come up with correlation coefficients between the choices (https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/stack-overflow-tag-network/discussion/41307), something that i do not know how to approach.

Comment: Can you post a small example dataset (real or simulated) for people to work with? Do you just want a picture of all connections, or is your ultimate goal to do something else, eg, cluster the choices? The examples you've linked to are intimately connected to clustering.